# Match all the list elements with a string and removing the string parts if matched

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-re

```
import re    
my_list=['apple', 'oranges' , 'peaches']
string= ' \apples\ \cherries\ \bananas\ \peaches\ \avocado\ \oranges\ '
for x in my_list:
    replace=re.sub(x,' ',string)
    print(replace)
```

correct output:- ' \cherries\ \bananas\ \avocado\ '

Where am i going wrong with this code ?

Comment: Why is `x` in quotes: `'x'`?

Comment: I don't understand. `'x'` just means a string with the value `x` in it. It doesn't mean `apple`, for example.

Comment: oh i see, i was mistaken, i edited it now , but still in the for loop , the loop iterates it for each element in list. is there a solution for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.replace()` and it might be easier:

```
my_list=['apples', 'oranges' , 'peaches'] # note typo in original post
string= r' \apples\ \cherries\ \bananas\ \peaches\ \avocado\ \oranges\ '

for item in my_list:
    thestring = '\\' + item + '\\ '
    string = string.replace(thestring, '')
print(string)
```

Output:

```
 \cherries\ \bananas\ \avocado\
```

However if there will be a variable number of spaces after the last backslash you might be better off using regular expressions and `' ?'` at the end of your search term.

In either case, the `print()` statement should be outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import re

a = ['apples', 'oranges' , 'peaches']
input_text = ' \\apples\\ \\cherries\\ \\bananas\\ \\peaches\\ \\avocado\\ \\oranges\\ '

output_text = re.sub(r'({})'.format('|'.join(['\\\\{}\\\\'.format(x) for x in a])), '', input_text)
```

`output_text` is:

```sh
  \cherries\ \bananas\  \avocado\
```